# Python - installing fapws with bottle

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to improve `bottle.py`-s speed by using FAPWS3. For this, I have installed bottle (it works fine), and installed `libev` and `fapws3` as described [here](http://www.fapws.org/getting-started). I can even see the libev and fapws3 install folders, however, I cannot import the module. I get `ImportError: No module named fapws`. What might I be missing? Linux distro:
`Linux 4.4.0-47-generic #68-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `fapws3` is not compatible with Python 3 yet.